# I want to display all of my whatsapp chat messages in my application. Please suggest

Tags: android

I want to display all of my whatsapp chat messages in my application.
I have done a lot of research on it, but still could not find anything working.

http://www.digitalinternals.com/security/decrypt-whatsapp-crypt7-database-messages/307
http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html

Except that I found some solutions which are providing access to the Whtasapp db on the rooted devices, but I want to access it on normal device.

Comment: What you have tried till yet.

Comment: Hi, you haven't shown us any code, or research effort. Show us what you have tried, the relevant code and the **specific** issues you are having. Read up on [how to write a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) and have a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on here. Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25284395/edit) your question and give all the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that you cant do this,because whatsapp db contents are encrypted and only decrypted by whatsapp.

Comment: Is there any  way that I can get notified when a message is received and sent from whatsapp, and that time I am able to access the data i.e. any kind of broadcast.

Comment: There are few unofficial Apl in github but its not recommended if you really want use it for whatsapp integration